# problem with thymeleaf template prefix using FileTemplateResolver and maven

Tags: java, maven, thymeleaf

I have a maven project (not spring boot) that I am working on that uses thymeleaf to create some html.
I have everything working in a test environment, but when I tried to run the app off a jar I got an error message.

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "C:\myapp\target\src\main\resources\templates\secmain_report_template.html")
```

I have my template resolver configured like so:

```
public TemplateEngine getTemplateEngine(String templatePrefix, String templateSuffix) {
    
    FileTemplateResolver templateResolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setPrefix(templatePrefix);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(templateSuffix);
    templateResolver.setCacheTTLMs(3600000L);
    
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    
    return templateEngine;
}
```

when I set my template prefix to `src/main/resources/templates/`, everything runs ok in test. but when running the jar I got the error above.

Looking at my target dir, I see
'my-app/target/classes/templates` and my template is there.

`src/main/resources/templates` is the default template location, but when commenting out the setPrefix() line, I got the error
`An error happened during template parsing (template: "C:\my-app\secmain_report_template.html")`

Any ideas?
thanks!

I tried

- commenting out the setPrefix() method
- changing the value to "", templates/, resources/templates and any other variation I could find.

Comment: Don't set the `templatePrefix` string to a full drive-and-directory path. Set it (in your case) to `/templates/` because when Maven builds the JAR, that directory will be included in the JAR (unzip the JAR to see for yourself).

Comment: I will leave the above comment (note the leading `/`) but now I think maybe it's not the right suggestion. In your final bullet point, you mentioned some of the things you tried (I missed them the first time around - sorry about that). Can (a) you clarify what you tried, and format the text, for clarity? Also (b) what is the full stack trace of the error? Can you add that to your question?